# Strange behavior setting bits

Tags: c++, binary

I'm working on a system that requires me to be able to set the individual bits that make up an integral type.

I wrote a program to test the usage of some binary operators. The following is a small example that uses the binary OR operator to set bits to true. But the behavior is confusing to me. If I loop through, setting each bit to true, it suddenly sets all bits to true after the 31st bit. I'm not sure why this would be considering I'm on a 64 bit machine and I'm using `numeric_limits` to get the number of bits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <limits>

int main() {

  typedef unsigned long long ullong;
  ullong bits;

  for(int i = 0; i < std::numeric_limits<ullong>::digits; ++i) {
    bits |= (1 << i);
    std::cout << std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<ullong>::digits>(bits) << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is as follows:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111
0000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: `1` is an integer, you are overflowing it. Try `1ULL` instead.

Comment: Why not using `std::bitset`??

Comment: I meant, why not using it in 1st place?

Comment: I'm not using the bitset because in the final implementation it has to be thread safe and lock free. What I'm actually using is `std::atomic<unsigned long long>` because you can't guarantee lock free operations on a std::bitset. I didn't put the atomic stuff in there because it adds unnecessary details to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because 1 is treated as an integer and as such, when it is extended to a 64-bit integer, it is sign-extended. Unsigned integers are zero-extended instead.

These are two different behavior of integral extension. Integral extension is what happens when an integral type is transformed into a larger integral type: the computer obviously can't just make the new bits random, so instead compilers pick one of two consistent behaviors.

- Sign extension takes the sign bit and repeats it for all the new bits of that integer: that way, if you take an `int` and make it a `long`, it'll still be the same number with the same sign. This is what typically happens when you extend signed integers.
- Zero extension pads with zeroes instead, and whatever the number was, it will now be positive (but if it was a positive number, it remains unchanged). This is what typically happens when you extend unsigned integers, for which you treat the sign bit as a regular number bit.

You'll also need to tell the compiler that 1 is at least as big as your `bits` variable, because otherwise the 1 is going to "fall off" when you shift: you're shifting it further than the size of an int, so it will be discarded. You can do that by either casting `1` to `ullong` (`(ullong)1`), or, more concisely, to use the `ull` prefix: `1ull`.

Comment: `i` is never converted to a 64-bit unsigned integer, it is used as a shift count.

Comment: Yeah, got it backwards.

Comment: It worth noting that when left shift attempts to manupulate the sign bit, the behavior is typically undefined. That happens before we even get to the matter of widening signed conversion. Left shift by 1 bit is effectively treated as multiplication by 2. And once that multiplication gets out of range of the underlying signed type, the behavior is undefined. That's actually what the above code demonstrates. Dieter's answer is the correct one from the language point of view.

Answer (score 1):

From 5.8 Shift operators

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and
>   integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of
>   the promoted left operand. The behavior is undefined if the right
>   operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of
>   the promoted left operand.

The trouble starts when i becomes 32. In other words int32_t(1) << 32 is undefined behavior.